# Doctrine 2 using Composite Keys with Foreign Keys won't update collection

Tags: collections, orm, doctrine, foreign-keys, composite-key

I've tried something like "[Use-Case 3: Join-Table with Metadata](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)".
I've used "Cart", "Item" and "CartItem" objects.

I get the items like `$cart->getItems();`.

Let's assume that there are 4 items. Now I delete one item like `$items->remove(1);` to remove an item.

`$items->count()` tells me that one item has been removed (it says 3). Also when look in the code, I see that the collection has changed.

So when I flush, I expect that the CartItem will be removed, nut nothing happens. Even when I add the items again like `$cart->setItems($items);` nothing happens at flush time.

Deleting an item should be straight forward, isn't it? What am I doing wrong?

**Edit Edit Edit**

Even with a "normal" key it doesn't work. I've created some new objects:

**Soup**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Soups")
 **/
class Soup {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="SoupIngredient", mappedBy="soup", cascade={"persist"});
     */
    protected $soupIngredients;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->soupIngredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {

        // Return id.
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->name = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSoupIngredients() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->soupIngredients;
    }

    public function setSoupIngredients($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->soupIngredients = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Ingredient**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="Ingredients")
 **/
class Ingredient {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text", length=50)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="SoupIngredient", mappedBy="ingredient", cascade={"persist"});
     */
    protected $soupIngredients;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->soupIngredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {

        // Return id.
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->name = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSoupIngredients() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->soupIngredients;
    }

    public function setSoupIngredients($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->soupIngredients = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**SoupIngredients**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="SoupIngredients")
 **/
class SoupIngredient {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="float")
     */
    protected $quantity;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Soup", inversedBy="soupIngredients")
     */
    protected $soup;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ingredient", inversedBy="soupIngredients")
     */
    protected $ingredient;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function getId() {

        // Return id.
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getQuantity() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->quantity = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSoup() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->soup;
    }

    public function setSoup($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->soups = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIngredient() {

        // Return value.
        return $this->ingredient;
    }

    public function setIngredient($value) {

        // Set value.
        $this->ingredient = $value;

        // Return.
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I get a `Soup` object that has 5 ingredients.

```
// Get Soup #1.
$em->getRepository("Soup")->find(1);

// Get ingredients.
$ingredients = $soup->getIngredients();

// Remove ingredient #2.
$ingredients->remove(2);

// Well, let's flush.
$em->flush();
```

Nothing happens. I can remove the `SoupIngredient` with the `$em`, but I want to use it in a function (`$soup->removeIngredient($ingredient)`) so I don't always have the `$em` available. Is the only way to achieve this to use the `$em->remove($soupIngredient)` (then it will be updated at flush-time).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! `orphanRemoval=true` works like magic...

Stupid me!